# How to test an Android Service running in its own process

Tags: android, android-service, android-testing, android-espresso

I've got a service running in background on a separate process. This service does some logic upon two types of events :

- GPS events : the service implements LocationListener
- Some messages coming from activities bound to the service and handled via a Handler class.

I'm new to android testing.

I want to test some cases mixing messages coming from GPS and messages coming from activities, to prove that after receiving a serie of messages my service behave as expected.

What kind of tests should I setup to accomplish this ?

Thank you.

Comment: I know this is an old question but testing can be done in isolation on the jvm in which case Mockito is used to fake android elements and junit is used. Instrumentation test run on the android system using ServiceTestRule. is this a started or bound service? I see you are using messages not the more formal aidl interface to communicate activity to service. monkey runner can trigger random ui events to see if things will break under such stress

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this quite old thread ;-) I indeed finally ended up mocking most of the signals with mockito.